# refresh rate on CRT monitor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, monitor

So, I've got a geForce 650 Ti Boost, on a CRT monitor. My ubuntu is the latest, and I use Nvidias propietary driver. I've tried all the things that I know of to set my refresh rate to 85 hz. I'ts a old monitor, but it serves me just right. I've tried to set on nVidias control pannel, to no avail, and to use compiz manager, again to no avail.

Can you help me to find another way to set the refresh rate?

Comment: Can you post the model of the CRT monitor? Many of them didn't support 85 Hz.

Comment: It's a proview LF 777K. The strange part is that this higher refresh rates worked fine until I installed the new video card

Answer (score -1):

Type the following command in a terminal:

```
xrandr -r 85
```

But before that you have to make sure that the CRT monitor supports the new refresh rate.

Please type into a terminal the following command and paste the output: `xrandr`

Comment: it doesn't work.